Unexpected Results in C# Floating-Point Arithmetic and Typecasting
I'm encountering unexpected behavior in my C# code involving floating-point arithmetic and typecasting to integers. Here's a simplified version of the code:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int d0 = (int)(2.300000000000001 * 100D);
    int d1 = (int)(2.3000 * 100D);
    Console.WriteLine(d0);
    Console.WriteLine(d1);
    return;
}


In this code, d0 and d1 are both assigned the result of a floating-point multiplication cast to an integer.
The expected result for both d0 and d1 should be 230. However, while d0 correctly evaluates to 230, d1 is unexpectedly resulting in 229.
I understand that floating-point arithmetic can sometimes introduce small errors due to precision limitations, but I can't explain why d1 is yielding 229. Could someone help clarify why this might be happening and how to resolve it to get the expected result of 230 for d1?


Take a look at the results of var d1 = (2.3 * 100D); Console.WriteLine($"{d1:F16}"); - you say youre already aware of how IEEE floats cannot represent all numbers accurately, so hopefully you can accept that this is one of those where 230 is actually 229.999999999.. and casting to int is a flooring op

I thought about this issue (@flackoverstow), but I believe such errors occur on the lower significant bits, not the high bits that represent the higher numbers, after all, IEEE has 23 bits fractional parts.
As per your saying, I tried the following, and got the result value:
        double d = 2.3;
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F9"));

Here I got 2.300000000, which is correct!
With Excel, =INT(2.3*100) also returns 230, correct.
Also in VB, I get a correct answer of 230:
Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(cint(2.3 * 100.0))

End Sub

Following your example @flackoverstow, this is what is happening (why is it sometimes rounding up and other times rounding down?):
double d2 = (2.3 * 100D);
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
{
string format = d2.ToString($"F{i}");
Console.WriteLine($"F{i}  {format}");
}
Output
F0  230
F1  230.0
F2  230.00
F3  230.000
F4  230.0000
F5  230.00000
F6  230.000000
F7  230.0000000
F8  230.00000000
F9  230.000000000
F10  230.0000000000
F11  230.00000000000
F12  230.000000000000
F13  230.0000000000000
F14  229.99999999999997
F15  229.999999999999972
F16  229.9999999999999716

Er, yes, that's how rounding to a certain number of decimal places works! Sometimes it round up, sometimes down depending on whether the first digit you're cutting off is less than 5 or not! 3.14159 is: 3 (down), 3.14 (down), 3.142 (up), 3.1416 (up) ...

When you convert 299.999 to int and end up with 299, you're not "rounding down", you're truncating.  Rounding should always involve an error of 0.5 or less, but truncation can lead to an error of up to 0.999… .

So when you convert a floating-point number to an integer, you almost always want to do a true rounding operation, not a blunt truncation like the cast (int) will do.  One simple way of rounding while converting to int (assuming positive numbers) is to do something like (int)(2.3000 * 100D + 0.5).

@SteveSummit  Your solution is effective for rounding and scaling a floating-point number as in this case, but it seems to slightly deviate from the desired behavior for other cases where the goal is to extract and not round the first two decimal places. For instance, for a number like 9.316xxxx, the desired output is 931, but using your method (int)(9.316 * 100D + 0.5), it rounds to 932 due to the addition of 0.5 which is intended for rounding to the nearest whole number.
Btw, whoever marked this post as duplicate is wrong. Both posts discuss floating numbers but in different ways.

@AlbertZakhia I didn't realize you had numbers like 9.316 in mind.  You're right, that's a considerably trickier problem.  So there are really two questions here: (1) why did 2.3 × 100 give you 229, and (2) what's a better way to do what you're trying to do?  The answer to #1 is the duplicate: there is no such number as 2.3 in floating point; the closest you can get is some variation on 2.2999999.  But the answer to #2 is the tricky one, because if you want 2.3 × 100 to come out as 230, what would you want 2.2999999 × 100 to come out as?

So I encourage you to ask again, but focusing on question 2.  And you need to be clear on what you're really trying to do, and where these numbers come from.  Depending on what you're trying to do, floating point may not be the right tool for the job.

Hi @SteveSummit. I am not trying to do anything in particular. I was just running some unit tests where they did fail in cases where they were supposed to succeed. I felt like it was a topic worth analyzing, especially since I had correct results from both Exel and VB.

The number 2.3 is not representable in the IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”) type. The source code 2.3000 is converted to the nearest representable value, which is 2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875. (The next higher representable value is 2.300000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875, which is further from 2.3.)
Converting this to the decimal type produces a number around 2.299999999999999822364316… Multiplying that by 100 produces a value around 229.9999999999999822364316… Converting that to int truncates, producing 229.

… I believe such errors occur on the lower significant bits, not the high bits that represent the higher numbers…

Effects on lower bits carry to higher bits. Subtracting any positive amount from 230 produces a number less than 230, no matter how small the amount subtracted is.
